# Is there a way in Java to have mutually exclusive options handled by the compiler?

Tags: java, class, methods, types

I'm wondering if there's a way to declare a method that takes a String and an Enum, but only require the string to be used if a certain enum is used.

Example:

```
public enum SearchType {
    REGEX,DEFAULT
}
public static List<File> Search(String path, SearchType search, String pattern) {
    //do things
}
```

**Ideally**, the pattern string field would only be required for the programmer to specify if they used the specific `SearchType.REGEX`, and if you either forgot it, or included it on a `SearchType.DEAFULT`, your program would not compile.

As it stands, the programmer would have to pass in an empty string if they're using `SearchType DEFAULT`, and the the code must check using a couple of `if` statements for the mutually exclusive options. Right now I have it throwing an IllegalArgumentException if you include a pattern with DEFAULT or forget the pattern on a REGEX, since both of those things indicate the person using this function probably made a mistake.

My questions are:

- Is this kind of compile-time parameter checking even possible with Java 8?
- is there a more idiomatic/safe/logical way to handle this case?

This sounds like it would be handled by an Interface of some kind if it can even be done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do compile-time parameter checking in Java 8.

However, you could write this in a cleaner way with [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).  Something like this:

```
public static List<File> Search(String path, SearchType search, String... searchArgs) {
    if (search == SearchType.REGEX) {
        if (searchArgs.length != 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Improper number of arguments for regex search: Expected 1, got " + searchArgs.length);
        }

        //Do the search
    }

    if (search == SearchType.DEFAULT) {
        if (searchArgs.length != 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Improper number of arguments for default search: Expected 0, got " + searchArgs.length);
        }

        //Do the search
    }
}
```

That way, it can be called like this:

```
Search("C:\\", SearchType.REGEX, "[a]");
Search("C:\\", SearchType.DEFAULT);
```

You still won't receive a compile error if you call it the wrong way, though.

Answer (score 5):

You should declare two methods: one method is called to do one job, not two. So here, you can declare:

```java
public static List<File> search(String path);
```

and

```java
public static List<File> search(String path, String pattern);
```

Your enum `SearchType` is useless in that case. Remember to add javadoc to your methods and the user won't be confused.

Comment: I totally forgot that you could do this (I'm still somewhat new to java-isms), so thanks, but I've actually got five different search types going in the real program, which is what led to the whole enum thing in the first place.